# Parallelization/Optimization of R loops containing *apply

Tags: r, optimization, combinations, doparallel

I am working on implementing an algorithm where I try to find 5 vectors out of 20 which are "furthest apart", using some measure. To do that i use [combnPrime](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gRbase/versions/1.8-3.4/topics/combnPrim) where I get a list of some 77000 vectors representing all 5-vector grouped combinations. Each vector has around 25.

To parallelize the below loops, I tried doParallel library, but I keep messing it up somehow and get -inf as a result. I read the doParallel documentation and could not apply what I saw there to my case, it is highly probable that my lack of knowledge of R makes the problem seem a bit harder than it actually is

```
#df2can be thought of as (thanks to @Oliver):
df2 <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(10)))
names(df2) <- LETTERS[1:20]


comb <- combnPrim(df2,5)
range <- length(comb)/5
result_vector <- vector(mode="list",length = range )
for (i in seq(range))
{
     total <- as.numeric(0)
     for ( j in seq(4))
     {
          for ( k in seq(j+1,5))
          {
              diff <- sum( ( mapply( '/',unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] ), ( unlist(comb[,i][j] ) + unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / 2 )^2))
              total = total + diff
          }
     }
     result_vector[[i]] <- total
}
```

So the question is how could I approach this problem to make this computation run faster. My approach was to parallize the outer most loop, where `range`variable is ~15000. All threads would need access to comb and share the variable `result_vector`. I believe my approach is not impossible but I would need some guidance.

Comment: added a comment briefly giving info about the nature of df2, hope that is adequate.

Comment: @life_steal, i suggest a reproducible example such as `df <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(10)); names(df) <- LETTERS[1:20]`. This should make it simpler for users to help out with your question.

Comment: @Oliver added your suggestion, thank you.

Comment: Why you need `mapply('/',  ..., ...)`? Why not `... / ...` ?

Comment: @Cole editted the combnPrim function now, without simplify=FALSE it should work.

Comment: @jogo well, turns out it is a good question. ```diff <- sum( ( (unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / (( unlist(comb[,i][j]) + unlist( comb[,i][k] ) ) / 2 ) )^2 )``` works already 3 times faster than the version in the question. Thanks!

Comment: I can not install the needed packages for R 3.6.1

Comment: @jogo [gRbase](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gRbase/index.html) should be the only dependency here. I have not tried it on R 3.6.1 though, I have R 3.5.3.

Comment: @jogo I had problems as well: https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RBGL.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach relies on creating a helper function and then doing the inner loop using the base `combn()` function.

```
fn_dist <- function(x, y){
  sum(((x - y) / ((x+y) / 2))^2)
}

system.time({
result_vector3 <- apply(comb, 2, function(comb_i) sum(combn(5, 2, FUN = function(x) fn_dist(comb_i[[x[1]]], comb_i[[x[2]]]))))
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.12    0.00    1.15
```

The use of `apply` was intentional as `future_apply` is very easy to use. Unfortunately, it performs worse for my 2-core machine:

```
library(future.apply)

plan(multiprocess)

system.time({
  result_vector_future <- future_apply(comb, 2, function(comb_i) sum(combn(5, 2, FUN = function(x) fn_dist(comb_i[[x[1]]], comb_i[[x[2]]]))))
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.59    0.03    1.92
```

If you prefer a for loop, these small changes make it similar in performance to the regure `apply` statement:

```
system.time({
for (i in seq(range)){
  total <- as.numeric(0)
  comb_i <- comb[, i]
  for ( j in seq(4))
  {
    for ( k in seq(j+1,5))
    {
      diff <- fn_dist(comb_i[[j]], comb_i[[k]])
      # diff <- sum( ( (unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / (( unlist(comb[,i][j]) + unlist( comb[,i][k] ) ) / 2 ) )^2 )
      total = total + diff
    }
  }
  result_vector[[i]] <- total
}
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.24    0.05    1.32
```

For reference, using @jogo's suggestion and removing just the `mapply` helps a lot but these workarounds help out a bit more.

```
system.time({
for (i in seq(range)){
  total <- as.numeric(0)
  # comb_i <- comb[, i]
  for ( j in seq(4))
  {
    for ( k in seq(j+1,5))
    {
      # diff <- fn_dist(comb_i[[j]], comb_i[[k]])
      diff <- sum( ( (unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / (( unlist(comb[,i][j]) + unlist( comb[,i][k] ) ) / 2 ) )^2 )
      total = total + diff
    }
  }
  result_vector[[i]] <- total
}
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.40    0.06    2.50
```

And finally, this is very similar to `dist`. If you are comfortable with the default methods, you could use:

```
system.time({
results_different_method <- apply(comb,2, function(l) sum(stats::dist(do.call(rbind,l))))
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.70    0.00    0.74

library(proxy)

system.time({
result_same_as_OP <- apply(comb, 2, function (l) sum(proxy::dist(do.call(rbind, l), method = fn_dist)))
})

#   user  system elapsed 
#   1.58    0.05    1.67
```

And I tried to get it down to a one liner but it was slower:

```
system.time({
result_final <- combn(ncol(df2), 5, FUN = function(cols) sum(proxy::dist(t(df2[, cols]), method = fn_dist)))
}) 

   user  system elapsed 
   3.71    0.08    3.80
```

I'll organize these thoughts more later.

Comment: The for loop version without unlisting in inner most loop provided enough performance. From 5 sec to 0.7 sec, thank you. (@joho as well )

Comment: `diff <- fn_dist(comb[j,i][[1]], comb[k,i][[1]]); total = total + diff` Using `apply()`for the outer loops is normally *loop hiding* (without much gain in performance)

Comment: @jogo not sure if the comment was for me or potentially critical, but I agree. At the same time,  sometimes there are no alternatives and ```apply``` can help - no reinitializing ```total``` for each loop and a user doesn't have to preallocate the ```results```. So, potentially no performance gain but could result in better coding although my ```apply``` statement is overly complicated.

Answer (score 1):

I tested two new variants (the functions `iloop()` and `cloop()`):

```
# https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RBGL.html
# if (!requireNamespace("BiocManager", quietly = TRUE))
#   install.packages("BiocManager")
# 
# BiocManager::install("RBGL")
# BiocManager::install("gRbase")

library("gRbase")
library("proxy") ## proxy::dist()
library("microbenchmark")

#df2can be thought of as (thanks to @Oliver):
df2 <- as.data.frame(replicate(20, rnorm(10)))
names(df2) <- LETTERS[1:20]

comb <- combnPrim(df2,5, simplify = TRUE)

ori <- function(comb) {
  range <- length(comb)/5
  result_vector <- vector(mode="list",length = range )
  for (i in seq(range)) 
  {
    total <- as.numeric(0)
    for ( j in seq(4))
    {
      for ( k in seq(j+1,5))
      {
        diff <- sum( ( mapply( '/',unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] ), ( unlist(comb[,i][j] ) + unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / 2 )^2))
        total = total + diff
      }
    }
    result_vector[[i]] <- total
  }
  return(result_vector)
}

nomapply <- function(comb) {
  range <- ncol(comb) ## length(comb)/5  
  result_vector <- vector(mode="list",length = range )
  for (i in seq(range))  {
    total <- as.numeric(0)
    for ( j in seq(4))  for ( k in seq(j+1,5)) {
        diff <- sum( ( (unlist( comb[,i][j] ) - unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / 
                         ( unlist(comb[,i][j] ) + unlist( comb[,i][k] )) / 2 )^2)
        total = total + diff
    }
    result_vector[[i]] <- total
  }
  return(result_vector)
}

ind <- function(comb) {
  range <- ncol(comb) ## length(comb)/5  
  result_vector <- vector(mode="list",length = range )
  for (i in seq(range))  {
    total <- as.numeric(0)
    for ( j in seq(4))  for ( k in seq(j+1,5)) {
      diff <- sum( ( (unlist( comb[j,i] ) - unlist( comb[j,i] )) / 
                       ( unlist(comb[j,i] ) + unlist( comb[k,i] )) / 2 )^2)
      total = total + diff
    }
    result_vector[[i]] <- total
  }
  return(result_vector)
}

nounlist <- function(comb) {
  range <- ncol(comb) ## length(comb)/5  
  result_vector <- vector(mode="list",length = range )
  for (i in seq(range))  {
    total <- as.numeric(0)
    for ( j in seq(4))  for ( k in seq(j+1,5)) {
      diff <- sum( ( (comb[j,i][[1]] - comb[j,i][[1]]) / ( comb[j,i][[1]] + comb[k,i][[1]]) / 2 )^2)
      total = total + diff
    }
    result_vector[[i]] <- total
  }
  return(result_vector)
}

range <- ncol(comb) ## length(comb)/5  

fn_dist <- function(x, y)  sum(((x-y) / ((x+y) / 2))^2)

iloop <- function(i) {
  total <- as.numeric(0)
  for ( j in seq(4)) {
    for ( k in seq(j+1,5)) {
      diff <- fn_dist(comb[j,i][[1]], comb[k,i][[1]])
      total = total + diff
    }
  }
  return(total)
}
# result_vector <- sapply(1:range, iloop)

cloop <- function(ci) {
  total <- as.numeric(0)
  for ( j in seq(4)) {
    for ( k in seq(j+1,5)) {
      diff <- fn_dist(ci[j][[1]], ci[k][[1]])
      total = total + diff
    }
  }
  return(total)
}
# result_vector <- apply(comb, 2, cloop)

# r <- apply(comb,2, function(l) sum(proxy::dist(method = fn_dist, do.call(rbind,l))))

microbenchmark(orig=ori(comb), orig2=nomapply(comb), orig3=ind(comb), orig4=nounlist(comb), 
               iloop=sapply(1:range, iloop), cloop=apply(comb, 2, cloop), unit = "relative", 
               proxy=apply(comb,2, function(l) sum(proxy::dist(method = fn_dist, do.call(rbind,l)))), 
               times=10)
```

These are the results:

```
# > microbenchmark(orig=ori(comb), orig2=nomapply(comb), orig3=ind(comb), orig4=nounlist(comb), 
#                  +                iloop=sapply(1:range, iloop), cloop=apply(comb, 2, cloop), unit = "relative", 
#                  +                proxy=apply(comb,2, function(l) sum(proxy::dist(method = fn_dist, do.call(rbind,l)))), 
#                  +                times=10)
# Unit: relative
#   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq       max neval   cld
#   orig 8.647526 8.648012 8.429268 8.597876 8.551316 7.1967369    10     e
#  orig2 2.613248 2.627175 2.564267 2.612007 2.633428 2.1851621    10    d 
#  orig3 1.949486 1.969982 1.911910 1.933789 1.963484 1.6318174    10  b   
#  orig4 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.0000000    10 a    
#  iloop 1.127511 1.146384 1.118755 1.149810 1.140409 0.9477470    10 a    
#  cloop 1.137061 1.154385 1.128315 1.149292 1.143234 0.9702812    10 a    
#  proxy 2.142964 2.127388 2.078447 2.100761 2.067607 1.9183790    10   c
```

The little changes in the inner loop gave the most performance gain:

- using `/` for the vectors (no `mapply()`)
- compacting the indexing (no double indexing) and
- using `...[[1]]` instead of `unlist()`.

To have clear code I would prefer the variant `cloop()` or using `proxy::dist()`.

Comment: I used the nounlist version with additional paranthesis and small index correction like below.
```R
diff <- sum( ( (comb[j,i][[1]] - comb[k,i][[1]]) / (( comb[j,i][[1]] + comb[k,i][[1]]) / 2) )^2)
```
Thanks!